# Should I include a default value for the argument passed into the constructor?

Tags: python, oop

I need to add an additional optional argument `from_strings` to the constructor.

Does this seem right? Or do I need to add a default value for `from_strings`?

```
def __init__(self, size=19, from_strings):
    assert 2 <= size <= 26, "Illegal board size: must be between 2 and 26."
    self.size = size
    self.grid = [['E'] * size for _ in range(size)]
    self.from_strings = from_strings
```

Because the constructor should be taking this:

```
b = Board(3, ["O.O", ".@.", "@O."])
```

Or should it be like this?

```
def __init__(self, size=19, from_strings=[]):
    assert 2 <= size <= 26, "Illegal board size: must be between 2 and 26."
    self.size = size
    self.grid = [['E'] * size for _ in range(size)]
    self.from_strings = from_strings
```

Comment: dont pass mutable object as default argument in function defination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your second proposal is better. However, you have to be aware of what would happen if you had two (or more) classes constructed using the default empty list. Better to default to None then test for that and assign a new (empty) list inside the constructor.

Consider the following:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, p=[]):
        self._p = p
    @property
    def p(self):
        return self._p

A1 = A()
A2 = A()

A1.p.append('Hello')

print(A2.p)
```

**Output:**

```
['Hello']
```

**A better approach:**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, p=None):
        self._p = [] if p is None else p
    @property
    def p(self):
        return self._p

A1 = A()
A2 = A()

A1.p.append('Hello')

print(A2.p)
```

**Output:**

```
[]
```

**Why does this happen?**

The default value (the empty list) is constructed once by the Python interpreter. Thus all instances of class A will have a reference to the **same** empty list. This is avoided in the second approach because a new / discrete empty list is constructed when needed

Answer (score 1):

In your case it is better to use the default value because of predictable function behavior.

In the first case, in addition, you have to swap arguments because first non-default argument should not follow the default argument.

Comment: oh okay so i should stick to the first option and swap the two arguments right

Comment: @AnneTillekeratne If you swap the 2nd and 3rd parameter declarations then *from_strings* becomes mandatory which may be all you need

Comment: @AnneTillekeratne If the `from_strings` is optional argument the better way is to set its default value to `None`. If you swap arguments without setting default value `from_strings` become mandatory.